# My ubuntu laptop is not booting

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-repair, initramfs

I have Ubuntu on my laptop and I can't boot to the os in the middle of the booting process I got a message saying

```
[    0.079681] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda2: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphanlinked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Comment: Can't you login even in the recovery mode?

Comment: no I can boot to the recovery mode.

Comment: what you did last time? Is your hard drive old or having issues? Try the same liveUSB and then try ubuntu

Comment: Nothing that's the weird part nothing computer only a year old.

Comment: Has ubuntu ever worked before this happened?

Comment: yes it worked before it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filesystem is corrupt.  At the prompt, type `e2fsck -fy /dev/sda2` to repair it.  If it works, hit ctrl-alt-del to reboot and hopefully it will come back up normally.

Comment: @HenryWHHack, note that unless you did something odd, like choose to use the old ext2 filesystem instead of ext4 when you installed, this is a strong hint that there is something wrong with your disk drive and you may want to replace it or at least run some tests on it.